# I am creating a table with a detaled row using React-Table and its hock useExpanded, but it doesn't working

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to create a table with a detaled row using React-Table and its hock useExpanded, but it doesn't working

Can any one help me pls.

My code is on codesandbox

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-table-expand-semwb

Answer (score 0):

I has just fixed the error.
The bug was on a duble declaration of useExpanded on the useTable hook ‍♂️

```
    const tableInstance = useTable(
        {
          data,
          columns,
          defaultPageSize: 10,
          showPagination: true,
          initialState: { expanded: false }
        },
        useSortBy,
        useExpanded,  <=======
\\      useExpanded,  <======= double declaration
        usePagination
      );
```